# Laravel 5.1 - How to dynamically prefix all registered routes

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-routing

**TL;DR: How to prefix all -already registered- Laravel routes?**

**Details:**
 - A large Laravel 5.1 application with third-party packages, each
   register it's own routes.
 - For some multilingual support, all routes have to be prefixed, without modifying these third-party packages.
 - As you know in Laravel 5.1 the router service is being bound very early
   before even custom service providers being called, so if router rebound the
   application will have a detached router.
 - So how could we prefix all currently registered routes?
 **- If no straight forward solution, in other words: how to replace the default \Illuminate\Routing\Router\Router::prefix()** which seems to be a possible solution..

Comment: Don't have an answer for you in laravel but you could trick all this using .htaccess mod-rewrite to re-write the URL with your prefix for all routes. Laravel does this out of the box actually to get rid of index.php. http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html

Comment: Thanks, but that's not acceptable solution at the moment. An application based solution required, not a server workaround.

Answer (score 2):

I know I'm bit late but in `Laravel 5.4` we can achieve something like this:

**Step 1** Create your package and create service provider in it.

**Step 2** Register your package service provider in laravel config app.

**Step 3** Now create a separate routes service provider which will contain following

```
namespace MyPackage\Providers;


use App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

class MyPackageRouteServiceProvider extends RouteServiceProvider
{
    protected $namespace='MyPackage\Controllers';

    public function boot()
    {
        parent::boot();
    }

    public function map()
    {
        $this->mapApiRoutes();

        $this->mapWebRoutes();
    }


    protected function mapApiRoutes()
    {
    Route::prefix('Mypackage\api')
        ->middleware('api')
        ->namespace($this->namespace)
        ->group(__DIR__ . '\..\Routes\api.php');
    }

    protected function mapWebRoutes()
    {
        Route::prefix('Mypackage')
            ->middleware('web')
            ->namespace($this->namespace)
            ->group(__DIR__ . '\..\Routes\web.php');
    }
}
```

**Note:** I'm considering there is `Routes Folder` and contain `web.php` and `api.php` file. According to your question you want to load it dynamically you can have a constructor function and pass the `package name`, `prefix` and `namespace` as per your ease.

**Step 4** Now the final step is registering the service provider you can call something like this in your package service provider:

```
public function boot()
{
    $this->app->register('Mypackage\Providers\MyPackageRouteServiceProvider');
}
```

Hope this help others. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

The best option for multilingual support without breaking the third-party packages is to remove the locale slug from the REQUEST_URI in the public/index.php .

```
$pattern = '/^\/(en|fr)\//';
$uri = filter_input(INPUT_SERVER, 'REQUEST_URI', FILTER_SANITIZE_URL);

if (preg_match($pattern, $uri, $matches)) {
    $uri = preg_replace($pattern, '/', $uri);

    $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] = $uri;

    define('LOCALE', $matches[1]);
}
```

There is a Laravel package Linguist what does exactly that and helps with URL and html anchor tag generation for multilingual enironment.

https://github.com/keevitaja/linguist

Answer (score 0):

You have posted no code snippet of your attempt, but seems that you are looking for [route groups](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/routing%23route-group-prefixes), which allows you to prefix, use middlewares and other stuff easily for a bunch of defined routes.

If you still need to add logic to your routing class you may wish to [extend it.](http://laravel.io/forum/02-12-2015-l5-extending-router)

Comment: Well, as I said above I don't need to mess with the third-party route groups, I'd like to prefix it all dynamically on the fly. A static application-wide prefix for all routes required. And yet, no code snippets required, it's a generic case: how to prefix all -already registered- routes?